# Drop-Down List in Automation Anywhere

Tags: drop-down-menu, rpa, automationanywhere

I need help with Automation Anywhere

- I have the following Drop-Down List and need to select an option.

< option selected="selected" value="">< /option >

< option value="0001">EUA OPT (0001)< /option >

< option value="0002">BRA OPT (0002)< /option >

< option value="0003">GER OPT (0003)< /option >

- I want the second option, BRA OPT (0002). In "Web Recorder" in the "Manage Web Controls" command there is a functionality to work with Drop-Down List.
  I can select the desired option for the "Select Item By Text" action, but it is only possible when I enter the full text -> BRA OPT (0002).
- How do I make the chosen option be selected by entering only the value? value = "0002"

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of the drop down list so that I suggest the best approach ?

Answer (score 1):

First idea that comes to my head is to "click" drop-down list with Object cloning, after that take the whole text from that list with Object cloning into variable_1. Search inside variable_1 for value that you are interested in, in this case "0002" and make some kind a regular expression to pick value of list element that you want. String operation before-after variable_1 before ")"  after "(0002)"
so will return you half of value of element you are looking for assign it to variable_2.

[image]

Result will be:

[image]

Last step is to concatenate variable_2 with "0002" and pass it to 
"Web Recorder.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to do so much to get what you need here. Automation Anywhere **"Select Item by Text"** works wonderfully with asterisk symbol ( * ).

If you want your robot to always select the second option regardless of its text value: Use **"Select Item By Text"** and put ***0002*** as value (including asterisks on both sides).
Or you could use ***0002)** to have hard match on value ending with **0002).**

Answer (score 0):

Will select the value from **Select item by text** after performing the manage web record command. ***Select item by text will give the exact value of the drop down which is present in the application***. 
**Another option is get the value which we want to select in drop down from any config file into a variable and then pass the same variable in **select item by text** option.**